# how to update multiple image that will store in different table using single action in yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, image-uploading

In this update action code only update data and upadte image on folder but does not updating another table tabl4e image

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->save();
            $cid = $model->id;

            if (isset($_FILES['attr_name']['tmp_name'])) {
                $photos = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('attr_name');
                $imgName = array();
                if (isset($photos) && count($photos) > 0) {
                    $DD = 0 ;

                    foreach ($photos as $image => $pic) {

                        $imagepath = Yii::getAlias('@image').'/';
                        $imageFileName = rand(10, 100).$pic->name;
                        $imageFile = $imagepath.$imageFileName;
                        if ($pic->saveAs($imageFile)) {
                            $imgName[] = $imageFileName;
                        } else {
                            //echo 'Cannot upload!';
                        }

                        $Image = new Image();
                        $Image->c_id = $cid;
                        $Image->image = $imageFileName;
                        $img = $Image->image;

                        if (isset($_POST['deletedImg'])) {
                            $pics = $_POST['deletedImg'];

                            foreach ($pics as $img1) {
                                $image = $img1;
                                unlink(Yii::getAlias('@image').'/'.$image);
                            }
                        } else {
                            $Image->image = $img;
                        }

                        if ($Image->validate()) {
                            $Image->save();
                        } else {
                            print '<pre>';
                            print_r($Image->errors);
                            exit;
                        }
                        unset($Image);
                    }
                }

                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

## jQuery

In this  code will getting multiple file button and store and delete  multiple images, i am getting delete image id, how to use this id on update action, i don't have any idea.

```
 $(".removeBtn").click(function(event){
    var img =$(this).attr("data-id");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var hiddenfield= '<input type="hidden" value="'+img+'" name="deletedImg[]" id=""/>';
    $("#deleted-img").append(hiddenfield);
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}); 
$(".btnAddRec").click(function(){
  var clonedHTML = $( "#fieldsRow" ).html();
  clonedHTML = clonedHTML.replace("<!--BUTTON-->",'<button type="button" class="removeBtn btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button>');
  $("#cloned").append('<div class="row" id="fieldsRow">'+clonedHTML+'</div>');
  $(".removeBtn").click(function(event){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
$("#cloned #fieldsRow:last-child input ").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $model->save();
            $cid = $model->id;
            $Image = Image::find()->where(['c_id' => $cid])->asArray()->all();

            if(!empty($Image)){
                if(isset($_FILES['attr_name']['tmp_name']) > 0){
                     if(isset($_POST['deletedImg']))
                        {
                            $pics = $_POST['deletedImg'];
                           // echo "<pre>";print_r($pics);exit;
                            foreach($pics as $img1)
                            {
                                $image = $img1;
                                unlink(Yii::getAlias('@image').'/'.$image);
                            }

                            $connection = \Yii::$app->db;
                            $delRec = $connection->createCommand(" delete image FROM image WHERE image='$image'");
                            $delRecExec = $delRec->query();
                        }
                    $photos = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('attr_name');
                    $imgName = array();
                    if(isset($photos) && count($photos) > 0)
                    {

                       foreach ($photos as $image => $pic) {

                        $imagepath = Yii::getAlias('@image').'/';
                        $imageFileName = rand(10,100).$pic->name;
                        $imageFile = $imagepath.$imageFileName;
                        if ($pic->saveAs($imageFile)) 
                        {
                            $imgName[] = $imageFileName;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //echo 'Cannot upload!';
                        }
                            $Image = new Image();
                           // print_r($Image);exit;
                            $Image->c_id = $cid;
                            $Image->image = $imageFileName;
                            $img = $Image->image;

                            if($Image->validate()){
                            $Image->save();
                            }else{
                                print '<pre>';print_r($Image->errors);
                                exit;
                            }
                            unset($Image);
                        }
                    }

                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); 
                }


            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                    ]);
        }   
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should start refactoring your code first.

For instance, you try to delete images in the loop where you iterate over uploaded images each time; have multiple assignments for image file name to Image model attributes and vice versa, unused variables (`$DD` ?) and probably more.

But I would recommend that you start looking at the official documentation first. There is even a code example for exactly this use case:

[Uploading Multiple Files](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md#uploading-multiple-files-)

High level approach: create a dedicated Multiple Images Upload Form (a model) and add all upload logic here.

Copied from the example:

**Model UploadForm**

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile[]
     */
    public $imageFiles;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) { 
            foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
                $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**View (the HTML form)**
Edit this to ad your jQuery scripts

```
    <?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

    <button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

**Your actionUpload in controller:**

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                return;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case you really should start debugging deeper in your app; make sure that the posted FORM data is actually what you expect it to be. The browser's code inspector is a good start, as is trace output in `runtime/logs.app.log` with your debug level set to verbose or trace.